# Does anyone make a tamper and weather resistant single receptacle outlet?

Tags: electrical

I have an older home that we are trying to update to three prong using GFCI.  One of the outdoor outlets will be protected by a GFCI, but the electrical box is slightly too small for the duplex outlet we purchased to fit.  The top and bottom of the outlet rub.  The outlet being replaced was a single receptacle, and one of those would fit, but I've only been able to find either tamper or weather resistant single outlets, not both, and most are 20 amp.  Does anyone make a 15 amp single outlet with both features?  The circuit it's going on is only 15 amp, so a 20 amp outlet is not a solution.

Clarifying the size issue, the box is deep enough to comfortably hold at least a slim GFCI if not a full size one, but it's a metal box and the rivets holding the ears of the box in place are about 1/16" too long for a (non-GFCI) duplex outlet to slide into place.  The rivets rub against the top and bottom of the actual outlet.  It's possible it's a case of a box that was slightly squeezed at some point, but the outlet it had in it originally was a single receptacle two prong that's old enough that it is able to accommodate the old style 120V plugs that look like modern ungrounded 240V 15 amp plugs.  I know there is a good chance I'll have to replace the box, but I'd prefer not to if possible.

Comment: Could you replace the box with a bigger one?  Might have to if the size is below space limits.

Comment: A GFCI located close to the point of use is the safest and least likely to be removed. GFCI receptacles even WR rated are usually less expensive than breakers

Comment: "Does anyone make..." probably.

Comment: It's looking like I probably will have to replace the box.  It

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to cram a GFCI into this box (probably isn't going to happen).  GFCIs have the ability to protect other legs of a circuit. Connect hot and neutral to the GFCI's "Load" terminals and -  well, that's what those terminals are for!  It's the only thing they're for.  You can place the GFCI protection along the circuit closer to the panel (or at the panel as a breaker, or right next to the panel as a GFCI receptacle in a box).

Now you can use a plain outlet in the cramped box.  TWR receptacles are available. We're not a "shop for me" site but [Google is](https://www.google.com/search?rls=en&q=twr%20receptacles&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8).

Outdoor receptacles definitely must be WR and **protected by** GFCI (which can be elsewhere).  Check with your local inspector - at my reading TR is required due to 406.12(A) and 210.52(E), but it seems redundant due to GFCI protection.

Comment: TR required below 5-1/2’ above that a standard or non tamper is allowed.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's vertical interference with the rivets holding the mounting ears of the box in place.  The outlet that won't fit is a standard WR/TR duplex, hence the need for a single receptacle outlet.

Answer (score 0):

Some receptacles have to have the ears or even the end tams snapped off to fit in some covers.

You can tell if it was designed to be snapped off by a deep crease in the metal. Almost all of the rings are 2 at each end are designed to be snapped off and some back and side there is an additional crease where the end 1/8” or so of the yoke is designed to be snapped off.

I have never had a UL listed receptacle, single gang that needed more than this to fit in a standard single gang box or even a bell box where the tabs, ears need to be removed to fit.

Tabs are easy to snap grab them with a simple pair of pliers or the gripping teeth on a pair of wire cutters fold away from the crease then back up they usually pop right off if not fold down again and they come off providing extra room so they fit.

Comment: Unfortunately it's the plastic of the back of the  outlet interfering with rivets on the top and bottom of the box.  It's probably an almost 70 year old box, so it's possible there's been some setting of the box, but if so it's not obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are outdoor outlet *boxes* that are both weather resistant and have facility for a padlock to provide tamper resistance.  If you need to put a GFCI in one it's not a problem, or as noted in another answer, since you're installing then indoors anyway, you could tap off one of those.

(I know you were probably referring to those outlets with plastic bits blocking the slots, but those are often more than just tamper-resistant, they are sometimes annoyingly everything-resistant.)

Comment: OP's requirement for "tamper resistant" is to comply with NEC requirements for the annoying plastic bits blocking the slots. Throwing a padlock on an "outdoor in-use cover" is not compliant. Those in-use covers are not boxes at all, they sit on top of the box and receptacle.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateUkraine I guessed OP's outlet was in a (to-be) outdoor play area.  Didn't know ... does NEC require *all* outlets to have those flaps now?  I still see (in NJ, 2017 I believe) more for sale without tamper proof than with!  And oh I hate them.  I love the British ones .... longer ground pin, door opener mechanism, sleeved power pins ... bloody marvelous.